Variable is not resolved in an Azure pipeline
I have defined a yaml file for a pipeline in Azure DevOps.
I want to define a variable named myVersion in Yaml which is structured as follows:
variables:
- name: myVersion 
  value: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)

jobs:
   - job: my_job
     steps:
      - script: echo '$(myVersion)'

The output is as follows:
 '$(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)'

Unfortunately, this does not work because the values are not resolved.
How can I fix this?

You may use format and counter expressions:
variables:
    a: $[format('{0:yyyyMMdd}', pipeline.startTime)]
    b: $[counter(variables['a'], 100)]
    c: $[format('{0}.{1}', variables['a'], variables['b'])]

jobs:
  - job: A
    steps:
      - task: CmdLine@2
        inputs:
          script: |
            echo $(a)
            echo $(b)
            echo $(c)

Result:


The variable value: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r) can only be used in Build.BuildNumber variable.
To solve this issue, you can use the following format:
name: $(Year:yyyy).$(Month).$(DayOfMonth)$(Rev:.r)


jobs:
   - job: my_job
     steps:
      - script: echo '$(build.buildnumber)'

Result:

Refer to this doc:Configure run or build numbers

In Azure DevOps $(Rev:r) is a special variable format that only works in the build number field.

